# Using a geometric series to calculate the sum of a power series-what is wrong?

Tags: power-series

Assume I need to calculate the sum of the following power series:
$$
S=\sum_{I=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^n y^n}{n}
$$

The first way is to substitute:
$$
t=xy \Rightarrow S= \sum_{I=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n t^n}{n} = -ln(1+t)=-ln(1+xy)
$$

The second way is to substitute:
$$
t=-xy \Rightarrow S=\int \sum_{I=1}^\infty  t^{n-1} dt = \int \frac{1}{1-t} =ln(1+xy)
$$

and the two solutions differ in a minus sign.
I suspect something is wrong with the second way, but can' figure out what. WIll you please help ?

Comment: $$\int\dfrac{dt}{1-t}=-\ln(1-t)$$

Comment: Great ! THanks ! I am an idiot